# Test a method with a private call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I use spring boot 3
I would like to do a test of a method who call another private method.

Private method is private because it get a token needed for other call.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
                .build();
    }

}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LcmApiService {

    @Value("${lcm.url}")
    private String lcmUrl;
    
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private  ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getToken(){
        ...
        return  restTemplate.postForEntity(lcmUrl + "/token", request, ApiResponse.class);

    }

    public  ResponseEntity<CreateUserReponse> createUserB2C(CreateUser createUser){ 

        ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> apiResponse = getToken();
        if(apiResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){

            JSONObject createuserParam = new JSONObject();
            createuserParam.put("name" , createUser.getName);
            ...
            
            HttpEntity<String> request =
                new HttpEntity<>(createuserParam.toString(), headers);

            return restTemplate.postForEntity(lcmUrl, request, CreateUserReponse.class);


        }

      ...
    }
}
```

I tried

```
@SpringBootTest
class LcmApiServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private LcmApiService lcmApiService;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void createUserB2CTest(){

        CreateUserRequest request = new CreateUserRequest();

        CreateUserResponse response = new CreateUserResponse();


        ResponseEntity<CreateUserReponse> responseEntity =  lcmApiService.createUserB2C();


        Mockito
                .when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), CreateUserReponse.class))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);


        assertTrue("succes", response.getBody().isSucces());

    }

}
```

So i search the easier way to do it. Because there is 2 rest template call, one private, I don't know how to start.

powermock seem to manage private but support only junit 4

Comment: Consider looking at this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-unit-test-private-methods

Comment: i want to test a method who call a private method... link is not very usefull

Comment: have a look of ReflectionTestUtils , it will help to test private method.

Comment: check with Powermock for you private method and use like you do for the rest